# Convert YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.F to oracle date format while insert

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

We stored the date as `VARCHAR2` in our database table

- REGDATE - `VARCHAR2`, Format `YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss.f`

Sample data:

```
2018-01-31 23:47:35.0
2018-01-01 00:00:48.0
2018-01-01 06:54:36.0
```

I'm trying to insert this data into a new table `TABLEB` with the correct `DATE` format. I tried a few solutions like below one's and i usually get `ORA-01821: date format not recognized`

```
SELECT 
    TO_DATE(REGDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.F') 
FROM 
    TABLEA 
WHERE 
    REGDATE LIKE '2018-03-16%'
```

Can someone please assist me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

You're right, Oracle does not support fractional seconds with the DATE format. This is also written on the linked website of the original answer... oops.

> The following datetime format elements can be used in timestamp and interval format models, but not in the original DATE format model: FF, TZD, TZH, TZM, and TZR.

This should work though:

```
SELECT CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP(REGDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF1') AS DATE) FROM TABLEA WHERE REGDATE LIKE '2018-03-16%'
```

**Original answer**

Try to use

```
SELECT TO_DATE(REGDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF1') FROM TABLEA WHERE REGDATE LIKE '2018-03-16%'
```

as found as explanation for element *FF* at the table *Table 2-15 Datetime Format Elements* on the website https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924

Comment: I'm getting this error "ORA-01821: date format not recognized" again with the query you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you very much Max. the updated query works perfectly. And thanks for the detailed explanation also :)

Answer (score 2):

To use fractional seconds, you need to convert to a `timestamp`, so:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(REGDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')
FROM TABLEA
WHERE REGDATE LIKE '2018-03-16%';
```

If you need this as a `date`, convert afterwards:

```
SELECT CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP(REGDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') as DATE)
FROM TABLEA
WHERE REGDATE LIKE '2018-03-16%';
```

Comment: Hello Gordon, i'm getting "ORA-01821: date format not recognized" with both the solutions.

Comment: @SaiAvinash - the lone `F` isn't valid and is causing that error; that should be `FF`, optionally with the number of fractional digits as Max used (but that isn't really needed converting this way).

Comment: @SaiAvinash . . . Do you know what's pathetic?  I actually tested the answers, put in the double "FF", and copied back the wrong version.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(REGDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') 
    FROM TABLEA WHERE REGDATE LIKE '2018-03-16%'
```